# Orthogonality condition in van der Vaart

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, proof-verification

I have a question related to the proof of Theorem 11.1 in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics" p.154 which can be found [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=van%20der%20vaart%20theorem%2011.1&source=bl&ots=mnSCND90Iu&sig=E552rDfddjvaS-fgCfa8djKoZqU&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv6vT4t5rKAhVFvBoKHfYiAWsQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=van%20der%20vaart%20theorem%2011.1&f=false)

The question is related to the assertion

> "the parabola $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha^2E(S^2)-2\alpha
>  E(T-\hat{S})S$ is nonnegative if and only if  the orthogonality
>   condition $E(T-\hat{S})S=0$ is satisfied"

Could you help me to understand why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(\alpha) = a\alpha^2 - 2b\alpha$ where $a\geq 0.$

If $a=0, b=0,$ then $f(\alpha) = 0.

If $a=0, b\neq 0$ then $f(\alpha)$ is linear in $\alpha$ and is a negative number for $b=+1$ or $b=-1.$

If $a>0,$ then $\min_\alpha f(\alpha) = f\left(\frac ba\right) = - \frac{b^2}{a}<0$ unless $b=0.$

Looking at all these cases, it follows that $f(\alpha)$ takes only non-negative values only when $b=0$.

Substitute $a = \mathbb{E}S^2$ and $b = \mathbb{E}(T-\hat{S})S.$